# How to calculate alias MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, alias, calculation, cumulative-sum

```sql
SELECT SUM(h.tb_handling_durasi)/60 as bd_total,
       day(last_day('2012-03-22')) as total_hari,
       (SELECT total_hari)*11*COUNT(i.tb_inventory_no) as plan,
       (SELECT bd_total)/(SELECT plan) as presentase
       SUM(SELECT bd_total) as total_bd
FROM tb_handling as h 
INNER JOIN tb_working_order as w ON h.tb_handling_working=w.tb_working_no 
INNER JOIN tb_inventory as i ON h.tb_handling_kode_inv = i.tb_inventory_no
WHERE month(tb_handling_selesai_waktu)=3 
AND tb_inventory_jenis="Laptop";
```

I have a problem with calculation alias "presentase" and "total_bd". What's wrong with writing this syntax alias "presentase" and "total_bd"?

Comment: Aliased columns are not available 'further down' in the select portion of the query. You could repeat how the aliased column is constructed to get rid of the syntax error.

Comment: you must have a comma after presentation, so that mysql knows there is a new column, and like P.Salmon sid, you can't use alias as exist only fter the qiery has run.

Comment: Your query is obviousy wrong. It demonstrates that you want to perform double gropuing  (bd_total is an aggregate, but you aggregate it in total_bd). Use subquery with low-level grouping and outer query with upper-level grouping.

Comment: https://xyproblem.info Post the task itself.